# update a single record for 200 concurrent user in postgres

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a single record containing the version, initially `1`.
`200` concurrent users are updating the same record, every update version should increase by `1`.if everything goes proper, then version must be `200`.

I am unable to update the record properly.

```
Max connection pool size = 50
Database = Postgres
```

Could you please suggest?
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I am able to make database procedure call for 200 times

Comment: How do you update the version number? I think that setting the transaction serialization level to Serializable would solve your problem

Comment: I configure the TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE ,but still i am getting the below issue - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for anything complicated here, and no need for explicit transactions management.

All involved sessions just issue

```
UPDATE mytab
SET version=version+1
WHERE key=42
RETURNING version;
```

By default each statement runs in its own transaction, and these transactions will lock each other out with an exclusive lock on the row, so they will be serialized automatically.

Comment: I configure the TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE ,but still i am getting the below issue - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make it clearer (I hope). There is no need for explicit transactions. Of course it may be that you need transactions for other reasons. On isolation level `REPEATABLE READ` and higher serialization errors can occur, and they are to be expected. That just means that you should retry the transaction. If there are too many conflicts, the "optimistic locking" approach used by these isolation levels is not appropriate and you might have to explicitly lock the table.

Comment: Thank you very much